# Problem with foreach for an array in PHP

Tags: php, email

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($all)) {
$name = $row->name;
$email = $row->email;
$id = $row->id;

$finished_text = '';
$news_content = '';
$buffer = '';

[...]

foreach($text_in_array as $word) {
    if($word == '[NAME]'){
        $buffer = $name;
    }else if($word == '[NAME].'){
        $buffer = $name.'.';
    }else if($word == '[NAME],'){
        $buffer = $name.',';
    }else if($word == '[NAME]!'){
        $buffer = $name.'!';
    }else if($word == '[NAME]"'){
        $buffer = $name.'"';
    }else if($word == '"[NAME]'){
        $buffer = '"'.$name;
    }else if($word == '"[NAME]"'){
        $buffer = '"'.$name.'"';
    }else if($word == '[NAME]."'){
        $buffer = $name.'."';
    }else if($word == '[NAME],"'){
        $buffer = $name.',"';
    }else if($word == '[NAME]!"'){
        $buffer = $name.'!"';
    }else if($word == '*[NAME]*'){
        $buffer = '*'.$name.'*';
    }else if($word == '**[NAME]**'){
        $buffer = '**'.$name.'**';
    }else if($word == '[EMAIL]'){
        $buffer = $email;
    }else if($word == '[EMAIL].'){
        $buffer = $email.'.';
    }else if($word == '[EMAIL],'){
        $buffer = $email.',';
    }else if($word == '[EMAIL]!'){
        $buffer = $email.'!';
    }else if($word == '[EMAIL]"'){
        $buffer = $email.'"';
    }else if($word == '"[EMAIL]'){
        $buffer = '"'.$email;
    }else if($word == '"[EMAIL]"'){
        $buffer = '"'.$email.'"';
    }else if($word == '[EMAIL]."'){
        $buffer = $email.'."';
    }else if($word == '[EMAIL],"'){
        $buffer = $email.',"';
    }else if($word == '[EMAIL]!"'){
        $buffer = $email.'!"';
    }else if($word == '*[EMAIL]*'){
        $buffer = '*'.$email.'*';
    }else if($word == '**[EMAIL]**'){
        $buffer = '**'.$email.'**';
    }else{
        $buffer = $word;
    }

    $news_content .= ' '.$buffer;
}
$finished_text .= Markdown($news_content);

[...]

mail(
    'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', //just test later it will be set to $email
    $betreff,
    $message,
    $header
);
}
```

I don't know why, but sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes it doesn't. Also interesting: Before I created a HTML email with this script, it only worked after I had changed the email address as the last change…

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get $text_in_array from ?

Comment: `sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes it doesn't` is not a useful error description at all... But anyway, this is crying out for a fundamental rewrite. Maybe the problem goes away all by itself once that has happened :)

Comment: German code? eww. Please use english for your identifiers etc. Besides that, the code is just horrible. Consider using string replacement...

Comment: @Pekka: Sorry. I can't describe it better, because I just don't understand it (for me it feels like random).

Comment: I don't think it's *that* terrible to use non-english identifiers if it's a hobby project. @NE well, you could show some input data and describe what happens when it doesn't work. But a rewrite would really be in order, maybe somebody who reads this can work out a suggestion

Comment: It's english now. And I'm writing it for a small newsletter of a friend in Austria… (nobody will see that code except for me ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should be using a `switch` statement instead of that long string of `if`s.
2. What's wrong with `$buffer = str_replace(Array("[NAME]","[EMAIL]"),Array($name,$email),$wort);`?
3. After cleaning that up, if you still get problems, please be more specific on what problems you are having.

Comment: Oh… thanks! I didn't think about 'str_replace();'! I'll try it and get back to you. Thanks so much!